# Power set of set containing empty set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to know the power set of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. 
The number of elements in 1 so the number of elements in the power set should be 2. Is the power set of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the power set of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is the set of all subsets of that set, i.e. $\{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$. Maybe more helpful for you, if we call $A=\{\emptyset\}$, then the power set of $\{A\}$ is $\{\emptyset, \{A\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The powerset of a set is the collection of all subsets of that set.  So, what are the subsets of $\{\{ \emptyset \}\}$?  Since the emptyset is a subset of any set, we have $\emptyset \subseteq \{\{ \emptyset \}\}$, and every set is a subset of itself, hence $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\{\emptyset\}\}$.  This set has no other subsets, therefore
$$ \mathscr{P}( \{\{\emptyset\}\} ) = \{ \color{red}{\emptyset}, \color{green}{\{\{\emptyset\}\}}\}.$$
(I've used color here to attempt to distinguish between all of the nested parentheses.  Apologies to those that are red/green colorblind—the distinction is not vital.)

Comment: @KaCy: If you find this post helpful, you have the choice of marking it as the answer to your question by clicking on the checkmark on the left.